# 80's TV-show about "digital" alien

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember one scene where the alien got shot. He pulled up his shirt and a blue grid (on black background) was there instead of regular skin, which then healed him.

The Movie "Starman" comes to mind, but I distinctly remember it as a TV-show, not a movie.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, because my memories of this show are vague at best, but could it be *Automan*? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lloeUkQ1m8

Comment: Welcome to SFF. Try to add as much detail as possible. You have a good start, but give our ID experts the best chance at finding at match for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is almost certainly [Automan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automan), a short-lived series from the early 1980s. The character was not an alien, but a computer-generated hologram.

Here's his blue skin:

[image]

Comment: Based on what I've been able to find about this show it seems to be the one I'm thinking about. I couldn't find the scene I described, where he got shot and magically healed himself, but I trust your expertise in the matter :)